# Can't connect to Node server on Amazon EC2

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

Here's the app.js, the code is too long so that's why I'm showing this code only, there's no problem in other code I assume this is a network problem.

**app.js**

```
app.listen(8080, 'localhost', function () {
    console.log('Express started on http://localhost:' + 8080 + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
});
```

I don't get any response when i run `lsof -i :8080`. but I do get response when I run `curl localhost:8080` on the server.

and I don't think there's any problem with security group. I allowed any ip to access to the instance as you can see below.

[image]

and here's actually how it looks like when I test `public ip` and `localhost`

```
ubuntu@:ip~/$ curl -v 18.217.107.76:8080
* Rebuilt URL to: 18.217.107.76:8080/
*   Trying 18.217.107.76...
* connect to 18.217.107.76 port 8080 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 18.217.107.76 port 8080: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 18.217.107.76 port 8080: Connection refused
ubuntu@ip:~/$ curl -v localhost:8080
I get response here!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I changed the code from

```
app.listen(8080, 'localhost', function () {
    console.log('Express started on http://localhost:' + 8080 + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
});
```

to

```
app.listen(8080, function () {
        console.log('Express started on http://localhost:' + 8080 + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
    });
```

now it's working

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me!!

In your security group you have added the rule HTTP which listens by default on port 80.

So basically if you have configured your node server to run on a port other than port number 80 (I was doing this mistake) and try to access the public DNS(EC2 public DNS can be found in instance description) on browser,  connection refused error might come so what you can do is change the PORT value in the config to 80.

Your config.env will look like this

```
PORT=80
```

And in your server.js you can write

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT;
try {
    app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`server running at port ${PORT}`) })
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```